# Jquery: "g is undefined". How to deal with this?

Tags: jquery, firebug

My script was working perfectly when I changed a few functions from a file to another and removed a few globals. Now when trying to load it I'm getting the error "g is undefined". I'm clueless of what that mean or where the error is coming from, because it's pointing to a jquery line and firebug won't give a full stack trace. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Did you touch any of the jquery files? If so, try replacing them with the originals.

Comment: Try again with the debug version (non-minified) of jQuery. Then you get better stack traces and source attachment.

Comment: did you changes versions of jquery ? also can we see what your new functions are , id guess that something that was golbal that you passed to some jQuery function is no longer defined

Comment: Not changed jquery files at all. Actually this is not even jquery code, this is a completely unrelated code using Three.js, so, wtf!? I just changed to: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js - is this the debug version?

Comment: Oh no, my question got abandoned again.

Comment: You said the error is in Jquery. Now it is Three.js? Get the non-minified versions of all of them.

Comment: what version of jquery where you previously running ?

Comment: The error is pointing to a Jquery line, even though I wasn't dealing with Jquery at all (it's used in other, minor parts of the page so it's loaded). I'm as confused as you. I solved the problem with a few ctrl+z's and recoding the stuff (???) but this is weird.

Comment: mcgrailm don't know, but 1.7.1 gave the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you changed the jQuery files and forgot to copy a necessary part of the script

Good luck!